# Can't connect Docker CLI to the remote Docker demon inside minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I can't connect Docker CLI to the remote Docker demon inside minikube.

I've done `minikube delete` and then `minikube start --driver=hyperv`   but when I do & `minikube -p minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression` it comes back with a weird error which is:

```
You: The term 'You' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
Invoke-Expression: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
Invoke-Expression:
Line |
   1 |  & minikube -p minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression
     |                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The string is missing the terminator: '.
```

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: I'm using PowerShell 7, but I get the same error in 5.1

Comment: try "minikube docker-env" in cmd  then 
paste the error in image format

Comment: turns out that it's simply `minikube docker-env`  afterall...it does give you this...`You can further specify your shell with either 'cmd' or 'powershell' with the --shell flag.` you then wait about a minute and then you get `SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://172.24.249.102:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\andre\.minikube\certs
SET MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD=minikube
REM To point your shell to minikube's docker-daemon, run:
REM @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env') DO @%i"`

Comment: correct, you have to run the last FOR statement without REM

Comment: @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env') DO @%i"

Comment: thanks for speedy reply Abhishek....I've got some documentation tat says it should be `& minikube -p minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression`  ...maybe that's been deprecated or something

Comment: seems to work with the `REM` for me...

Comment: REM is a comment in batch script, 
glad its working now

Comment: & "C:\Program Files\minikube.exe" -p minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression

Comment: after I did `minikube docker env` and tapped enter..I then had to type `minikube -p minikube docker-env --shell powershell | Invoke-Expression` and then everything woked

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As already discussed in the comments the solution is to use the [minikube docker-env command](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/docker-env/):

> ```
> minikube docker-env
> ```
>
> Configure environment to use minikube’s Docker daemon
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> Sets up docker env variables; similar to `$(docker-machine env)`.
>
> ```
> minikube docker-env [flags]
> ```

Notice the `--shell` option:

```
  --shell string   Force environment to be configured for a specified shell: [fish, cmd, powershell, tcsh, bash, zsh], default is auto-detect
```